# how do I use different version of java

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc, java-6

I've installed both java 6 and 7 and using eclipse to write a simple jdbc application. I have both sqljdbc4.jar and sqljdbc.jar in the lib folder. I'm getting this message...

> Dec 18, 2013 9:29:51 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection
>
> SEVERE: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.

```
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.<init>(SQLServerConnection.java:304)

at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1011)

at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

at sqldriver.doConnection(sqldriver.java:27)

at sqldriver.main(sqldriver.java:12)
```

If I'm suppose to be using 1.6 how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Have you thought about following the advise in this error message (and sqljdbc4.jar is *also* for Java 6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
I needed to change the Run/Debug Settings > Edit > Execution environment
[image]

And there I go.
It's not a permanent fix but it will do for now.

Answer (score 10):

You need to remove `sqljdbc.jar` from the class and build path and **only** use `sqljdbc4.jar` (which is for Java 6 and higher).

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project --> properties and then Java compiler
 and then select the java version you need
[image]

Comment: -1, That doesn't actually change which Java version you use, and therefor doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [example](http://blogbynoob.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/java-connect-to-sql-server-using-jdbc.html). It's easier and you don't need to add the sqljdbc jars.

Comment: In my opinion it is not easier, and the OdbcJdbcBridge will be removed from future versions of Java.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I tried to import data from SQL Server into my Solr index (solr v1.4.0 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine). To fix the issue I deleted sqljdbc.jar from the solr lib directory and added sqljdbc4.jar to the same directory.