# eclipse says it's using JRE 1.7 even though it's using 1.6

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc

I'm trying to build a simple jdbc sql example. it's 1 class. I have both jdbc driver jars referenced it's runtime is JavaSE-1.6. It connects to a database I already have setup using this code...

```
// Load the JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        // Create a connection to the database

        connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=AboardTestDB;integratedSecurity=true");
        System.out.println("Connected DB successfully");

        // STEP 4: Execute a query
        // writes the tables in local and not on GANESHN1\SQLSERVER2008
        System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
```

And the thing is it worked before. It worked beautifully. But a colleague of mine was having trouble with it. so I removed a jar to get the same error as him. but when I put it back it gave me this error message (again)

> Dec 20, 2013 9:50:53 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection 
>   SEVERE: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.(SQLServerConnection.java:304)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1011)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at sqldriver.doConnection(sqldriver.java:23)
>       at sqldriver.main(sqldriver.java:59)

Everything else has stayed the same. I tried restarting, unstalling/reinstalling, creating a new project, trying different JRE's nothing. 
Is there something I'm missing here? something else I can try?

Comment: Have you set your JDK compliance level to 1.6 (right click on project -> Properties -> Java Compiler)?

Comment: Check the JRE tab of the run-configuration for your project. Maybe it has the "wrong" JDK/JRE set there. (But you really should be using the latest version of the JDBC driver.)

Comment: oh, it's 1.6 alright. and I already tried changing the Execution environment (which is how I got it to work the first time) still nothing

Comment: How is this different from the question you asked two days ago [how do I use different version of java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662692/how-do-i-use-different-version-of-java) And as I said then: you should only have `sqljdbc4.jar` on your classpath, even on Java 6!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind! I got it working again by removing one of the jars. The thing is, I had them both in there and it was working just fine before :P
Mysterious

Comment: The order of jars on the classpath is relevant. If two jars contain a class with the same name, the one that appears first on the classpath is loaded.